# Optimising for on-screen viewing

Tags: printing, screen

I have found some examples where a document, which is *not a presentation*, was nevertheless typeset with a papersize fitting screen aspect ratio:

- [A ConTeXt manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-eni.pdf)
- [Another ConTeXt manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/ms-cb-en.pdf)
- [The pdfscreen package manual](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfscreen/manual-screen.pdf)

These documents also have a corresponding "print version", with traditional papersize and design, probably created from the same source file with different preambles. The article mode of the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) class also seems to encourage this idea.

I'm interested in

- examples where this approach was used; was it successful, and why/why not?
- is this idea more prevalent in ConTeXt? is it easier to do this in ConTeXt than in LaTeX?
- other ways to do this in (La)TeX; documentclasses/packages I don't know about
- maybe other software more suitable for this than TeX systems. After all TeX is generally oriented towards printed material... or not?

---

**Some background:**

At my university they almost never distribute printed lecture notes. Instead, the material is always available online (in fact I heard that this is required from all lecturers).

In some cases the online material is in A4 form, written with Word or LaTeX; and in other cases the material is the lecture slides, created with LaTeX or PowerPoint. Some students prefer on-screen viewing and studying, and others print out everything.

Now I've read somewhere that the A4 scrolling format is not really pleasant for on-screen viewing. On the other hand printing a set of slides on A4 paper is not really economical.
The above documents give me the (purely theoretical) idea that teachers could (were they all using TeX) create screen and print versions of their material so that everyone can learn comfortably.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to prepare a "mobile" version, for 6 inch devices (ebook readers & tablets.)

Answer (score 6):

The MathML2 specification has (apart from its normative HTML version) [A4 formatted PDF, for print](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/mathml-p.pdf) and [4x3 Screen formatted version](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/mathml-s.pdf)

I dropped this for MathML3 as I saw no evidence that anyone used the screen formatted PDF.
People liked the pdf for printing and the HTML on-screen.

Not sure a sample of one is statistically relevant, but it is some sort of possibly related information.

The PDF are all generated with LaTeX.

Comment: This is important because it emphasizes that PDF may not even be the best format for the screen; HTML's layout is not fixed by default and so the text is reflowable, and the whole layout can adapt to the screen resolution. One can consider converting the TeX to HTML for on-screen viewing, or generating both from a common source, e.g. Markdown.